# Xamarin Forms - Add Android AutoCompleteTextView as native bindable view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

So with the option of native bindable views in Xamarin Forms I wanted to see if I could get the Android AutoCompleteTextView to work by adding to one of my xamarin forms pages. The control does render on the page in android and when I type a dropdown does display but the problem is the text in the suggestion drop down is white and as a result it's not easy to see. My questions are

1. Should I abandon this approach and try a custom renderer or implement a native view for this page instead?
2. If the path I've chosen is ok, how do I tweak the control to display the text in another color?

Here's the code for reference

The View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             xmlns:formsandroid="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             x:Class="AcoadApp.Views.AddMatchPage"
             Title="New Match">
  <StackLayout>
    <androidWidget:AutoCompleteTextView Adapter="{Binding OppAdapter}"  x:Arguments="{x:Static formsandroid:Forms.Context}" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The ViewModel

```
public class AddMatchViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        ArrayAdapter<Java.Lang.String> _oppAdapter;
        public ArrayAdapter<Java.Lang.String> OppAdapter
        {
            get { return _oppAdapter; }
            set { _oppAdapter = value;  OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public AddMatchViewModel(INavService navService)
            :base(navService)
        {
            OppAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Java.Lang.String>(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);
        }

        public override async Task Init()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        void LoadData()
        {
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Seaside"));
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Palma"));
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Aptos"));
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Harbor"));
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Salinas"));
            OppAdapter.Add(new Java.Lang.String("Anzar"));
        }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of the result (a suggestion from the ArrayAdapter is there...if you look close enough =] )
[image]

Any suggestions or pointers anyone may have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Edwin

--Edit
Here's the requested BaseViewModel class

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected INavService NavService { get; private set; }

        protected BaseViewModel(INavService navService)
        {
            NavService = navService;
        }

        public abstract Task Init();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you used some templates for your development? What is your `BaseViewModel`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Not using a template but I edited my post to incluse the BaseViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

**Use XLabs AutoCompleteView or use XLabs AutoCompleteView Droid code for customization**

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/AutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the Syncfusion Xamarin Forms package. They have a cross platform AutoComplete control that seems to work well. Here's the link if anyone is interested https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin